# FindFit for dimension reduction?

Tags: fitting

Given an n-dimensional function, can I use `FindFit` to produce an approximate (n-k)-dimensional function?
Here is a simplified illustration of what I am trying to do. I have
$$f(x,a,b,\mu,\sigma) = \frac{g(x,a)\,g(x,b)}{\sigma\sqrt{1+x^2}}\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$$
where $\phi$ is the $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ density, $a,b\in[-1,1]$, $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{*+}$ and 
$$ g(x,a) = \max(0, -ax+\sqrt{1-a^2}). $$
Here is the code to build such a function with Mathematica:

```
ND[x_]:= Exp[-x^2/2] / Sqrt[2*Pi]
G[x_, a_] := (-a*x + Sqrt[1 - a^2]) * UnitStep[(-a*x + Sqrt[1 - a^2])];
F[x_, a_, b_, m_, s_] := G[x, a] * G[x, b] * ND[(x - m)/s] / (s * Sqrt[1 + x^2])
```

I would like to approximate $f$ with the following Gaussian function
$$g(x,\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \frac{\alpha\gamma}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp(-(\gamma x-\beta)^2)$$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are functions of $a,b,\mu,\sigma$.
So if I create a table

```
Flatten[Table[{x, m, F[x, a, b, m, s]}, {x, -15, 15}, {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {m, -1, 1}, {s, 0.125, 2, 0.125}]]
```

can I use FindFit to yield $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ which will approximate $f$ ?

Comment: Offhand I would think so. Did it not give you reasonable results? Note: you will want to include values of all parameters, e.g. a,b,s as well as x,m, in your data list. If you were getting error messages, rather than a result, that could be the cause.

Comment: It does seem like the basic idea is OK. One thing is that you have a rather sparse sampling of your space. Since everything is spaced in integers, you only have 3 different values of `a`, `b` and `m`. I would suspect you would do better to have a denser sampling, for instance, `{a,-1,1,0.1}`.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the sampling density issue. But assuming I have an adequate table, how do I use it in FindFit ? I guess it would be something like  FindFit[%, {alpha*gamma*Exp[-(gamma*x - beta)^2]/Sqrt[Pi]}, {alpha, beta, 
  gamma}, {x,a,b,m,s}] but how am I supposed to inform Mathematica that alpha, beta, gamma are functions of a,b,m,s ?